# Understanding running time function

Tags: algorithm, analysis

I'm doing some self study for a difficult exam (for me), and I cant grasp the concept of execution time of algorithms using the T(n) function.

For example:

```
i = 1;                 // c1  1

sum = 0;               // c2  1

while (i <= n) {       // c3 n+1

    i = i + 1;         // c4 n

    sum = sum + i;     // c5 n

}
```

**Cost calculation:**

```
Total Cost = c1 + c2 + (n+1).c3 + n.c4 + n.c5

T(n) = an^2 + bn + c
```

Is finding the total cost enough?

Please bare with my noobness, any resources will also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Finding exact running time is usually useless, since it depends on many things including your compiler optimizations, your hardware architecture, the amount of programs you run, your OS, and more. \

A simple example: How much time will it take:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) 
   c[i] = a[i] + b[i]'`
```

The answer is - it depends. For example, many modern machines allow vector additions in a single instruction, that takes conciderably shorter than iterating and adding.

For the above reason, we seldom care for the exact theoretic time, and us the **[big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)** instead, or alternatively - compare running of some algorithm based on their actual performance - using **[statistical tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing)**.

The complexity of your code under the Big O notation is `O(n)` - since it involves iterating `n` elements, and doing some constant time modification for each.